How to retrieve sessionid and send commands to an existing browser session in leadfoot?
Preq:

We have a JS UI automation framework built on webdriverio & nodejs, on run, chrome browser launches and brings up a login page.

Then, I attach chrome debugger for debug purpose using NiM plugin, where scripts get paused.

Now, requirement is to gain access to current active session and send leadfoot command through nodejs.
 const requirejs = require('requirejs');

     requirejs.config({
     nodeRequire: require
    });                                                     

     requirejs(['leadfoot/Server', 'leadfoot/Command'], function (Server, Command) {                            try {
     const webDriverUrl = 'ws://127.0.0.1:59058/devtools/browser/3c60c241-a996-4771-b2b2-6e67f7c18019';
     console.log('Creating Server instance with URL:', webDriverUrl);
     const server = new Server(webDriverUrl);
     console.log('Server instance created:', server);

     try {
         server.getSessionCapabilities().then(sessionCapabilities => {
             console.log('Session Capabilities:', sessionCapabilities);
             const command = new Command(sessionCapabilities);
             const searchBox = command.findByCssSelector('textarea[name="q"]');
             searchBox.type(value || 'test')
         }).catch(error => {
             console.error('Error retrieving session capabilities:', error.message);
         });
     } catch (error) {
         console.error('Error during getSessionCapabilities:', error.message);
     }
 } catch (error) {
     console.error('Error during initialization:', error.message);
 }});



Result: On executing above script from nodejs cmd prompt, I get error as below:
Creating Server instance with URL: ws://127.0.0.1:59058/devtools/browser/3c60c241-a996-4771-b2b2-6e67f7c18019
Server instance created: Server {
  url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:59058/devtools/browser/3c60c241-a996-4771-b2b2-6e67f7c18019/',
  requestOptions: {}
}
Error retrieving session capabilities: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Note: I'm using websocket URL to establish a connection to existing browser session, is this correct or any other way to retrieve webdriver URL of an already launched session available in leadfoot?
